# Open drawer on clicking AppBar

Tags: flutter

If you create an Scafold there is an option for drawer. If you now create this drawer you get automaticly the menu icon on the leading position of the appbar. But i want an other icon there which opens the drawer. I tried to make an iconbutton myself on the leading position but this button can‘t open the drawer even with „Scafold.of(context).openDrawer()“ it can‘t open it.

Is there any option to replace the icon for the drawer button?

Comment: Sometimes you need to pay attention to the `BuildContext` that you are passing into the `Scaffold.of(context)` method. If that context is the same context that the Scaffold is being built in, that context won't know about the Scaffold, and hence `Scaffold.of(context)` will return null. You can wrap a widget in a `Builder` widget to build it with an updated context.

Comment: @JohnDengis wrapping an AppBar with Builder doesn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: @AndriyTrubchanin I didn't mean wrapping the AppBar but you can wrap the leading as shown in one of the other answers.

Answer (score 178, accepted):

Use a `Key` in your `Scaffold` and show the drawer by calling `myKey.currentState.openDrawer()`, here is a working code:

[image]

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestState createState() => new _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      drawer: new Drawer(),
      appBar: new AppBar(
        leading: new IconButton(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.settings),
          onPressed: () => _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This way if I click again on the IconButton the drawer is not closed.

Comment: @Augusto Is there a way to click the IconButton when the drawer is opened?

Comment: is that anyway to close?

Comment: @user9139407 call ‘Navigator.pop(context)’

Comment: @aziza, may I ask you to have a look at a Flutter related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60565658/fluter-image-picker-package-show-images-one-after-another-with-delete-action ?

Comment: openDrawer method does not show up if the GlobalKey is not cast as "<ScaffoldState>" and also don't forget to include "drawer: Drawer()," parameter of Scaffold

Comment: What is the disadvantage of using the global key is this case?

Comment: Latest version give error if there is no null check, rather use `_scaffoldKey.currentState!.openDrawer()`

Answer (score 119):

Alternative to the accepted answer which does not require a `GlobalKey`:

```
class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      drawer: new Drawer(),
      appBar: new AppBar(
        leading: Builder(
        builder: (context) => IconButton(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.settings),
            onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: There is an issue. https://www.reddit.com/r/FlutterDev/comments/7yma7y/how_do_you_open_a_drawer_in_a_scaffold_using_code/

Comment: @SuyonWon what is the issue?

Comment: Sorry you're right, you applied an additional Builder(). I missed.

Comment: I also wrapped the Icon widget with Padding widget so that it's exactly placed: Padding(child:Icon(Icons.menu),padding:EdgeInsets.all(8.0)

Comment: Best answer. Make your local BuildContext for the win.

Comment: I prefer this way, because it doesn't make use of Global key:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51329065/builder-versus-globalkey

Comment: Your solution is more practical.

Comment: Better because it doesn't use a GlobalKey, should be preferred instead of the most voted one

Comment: Thanks for this answer. i was developing an web app and i was having issues with opening the app drawer. this answer really helped.!!

Comment: This helped me understand the underlying issue. In my case, I wanted a button in a `BottomNavigation` to trigger the drawer, so `leading` isn't available. Simple solution: instead of creating the `OutlinedButton` directly, call `Builder(builder: (context)=>OutlinedButton...`. Makes sense: the `Scaffold.of` call needs a context within the scaffold, so adding a builder to _create_ the button does the job.

Comment: Scaffold.of() called with a context that does not contain a Scaffold.

Answer (score 13):

Using GlobalKey:

```
final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _key = GlobalKey(); // Create a key

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    key: _key, // Assign the key to Scaffold.
    drawer: Drawer(),
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () => _key.currentState!.openDrawer(), // <-- Opens drawer
    ),
  );
}
```

Using Builder:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    drawer: Drawer(),
    floatingActionButton: Builder(builder: (context) {
      return FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(), // <-- Opens drawer.
      );
    }),
  );
}
```

Comment: it worked but the drawer hamburger button still appear at the app bar

Answer (score 8):

you need initialize `scaffoldKey`
after that,

**Open drawer and close drawer**

```
 GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            if(scaffoldKey.currentState.isDrawerOpen){
              scaffoldKey.currentState.openEndDrawer();
            }else{
              scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();
            }
          },
          child:  LeadingIcon(icon: Icons.menu),//your button
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _scaffoldKey.currentState!.openDrawer();
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.home)),
        ),
        drawer: const Drawer(),
      ),

 - List item

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).