# Builder versus GlobalKey

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Numerous questions relating to building Flutter UIs come down to the wrong `BuildContext` (such as showing a `SnackBar`). The answers usually offer either of using a `Builder` or using a `GlobalKey`. Both work, but I noticed that the documentation for [GlobalKey](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GlobalKey-class.html) states:

> Global keys are relatively expensive. If you don't need any of the features listed above, consider using a `Key`, `ValueKey`, `ObjectKey`, or `UniqueKey` instead.

The features referred to are unique identification and subtree re-parenting. Is the "relative expense" of using a `GlobalKey` for these circumstances reason enough to use a `Builder` instead?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The real reason we tend to avoid `GlobalKey` is not about performance. It is more related to the fact that it breaks a few patterns in flutter.

Widgets by definition should not be able to access concrete information of other widgets (such as their size or position). And `GlobalKey` grant the ability to access such information; allowing peoples to do anti-pattern stuff.

Think of `GlobalKey` as a mean to *eject* the reactive layer of Flutter.

A few examples of what peoples are tempted to do using `GlobalKey` :

- Having a public singleton `GlobalKey`. Used as a mean to not *lift the state up*. Making interaction between widgets hard to predict, as the relationship isn't one-sided anymore (parent -> children becomes a two-way relationship)
- Using `GlobalKey` to compute the size of a layout. Then trigger a re-render with this information. This instead is the role of `RenderObject` and shouldn't be done in widgets. It makes layout much harder to maintain

---

`Builder` and similar on the other hand don't break these patterns. As, by definition `Builder` does *nothing*. It's just a neat way of using a different `BuildContext`.

This usually means that if you can solve your layout problem using `Builder` instead of `GlobalKey`, you're on the right track to a maintainable layout.

---

When to use `GlobalKey` then?

Well, if you can, never. Try to instead use things such as `context.ancestorStateOfType` or `context.inheritWidgetOfExtactType`. You may also want to consider creating a custom `RenderObject` for a specific layout. `RenderObject` combined with `parentData` may also be what you want if you need a relationship between parent/children

This can more complicated though. It can consume more time than you want. Or you may fall into an edge-case that is hard to implement using the current API.

In such situations, it is ok to use `GlobalKey` as long as you know the potential consequences.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer; that makes sense. Perhaps the docs should be clearer on the real reasoning and some use cases on when it's OK to use `GlobalKey` and when it's not :)

Comment: @rémi-rousselet, To compute the size of a layout , instead of using Global key what to use?

Answer (score 9):

`GlobalKey` being expensive is most likely related to situations where you might need lots of keys, like for the children of a `ListView`.

I doubt the cost of a `GlobalKey` for a `SnackBar` will matter. It's unlikely that you create a lot of them.

Comment: This is what you were saying. Read it here now. I am also updating that solution by inserting a link of this answer plus upvoting it too.

Comment: so is it okay in terms of performance and memory to use `GlobalKey` to show `Snackbar` as long as we have just one `GlobalKey` in the entire widget assigned to the `Scaffold`?

Comment: I think so. Don't use GlobalKey for items in a list with hundreds of items.

Comment: But why? Can you please explain, why one should not use GlobalKeys for many items? Does it decrease my performance?

Comment: The Flutter documentation states, that it is expensive (lots of computation). So if you have some specific situation where you benefit from it, it's probably a good idea to use it. If it's not strictly necessary, better try to avoid it.