# Flutter calling child class function from parent class

Tags: dart, flutter

**Code**:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.help),
            onPressed: () {
              // how can I call methodA from here?
            },
          ),
        ),
        body: HomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }

  void methodA() {}
}
```

**Question**:
I want to call `methodA()` from `onPressed()` of `IconButton`. How can I do that, I know how to call parent's method from child class but this use case is different.

Comment: You can pass a GlobalKey to `HomePage(...)` and use this key to access `HomePage`'s state. It's better to use some event propagation mechanism though (BloC and redux help here but there are many ways to do that)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks for the hint, I know `ScopedModel`, can that also help here? IMO, that won't help because that is used to pass the data down the tree.

Comment: Never had a closer look. You can also use a plain `StreamController` and pass it's stream to the child component and in the child component listen to the stream. In the parent you add to the `StreamController` and the listener (child) calls `methodA` for each event.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I used `GlobalKey` approach, the code is now working, can you please check if I did it the correct way?

Comment: Yes, it's fine.

Comment: Many thanks @GünterZöchbauer. I have never used `StreamController` so I used `GlobalKey`.

Comment: `GlobalKey` is fine for this use case because there is only one such element in your whole application. Don't use it for example for elements in a `ListView`. `GlobalKey` mentions in the docs that it's expensive. That won't hurt if you create one, but likely does if you create hundreds. There are lots of articles about streams and architecture (BloC, Redux, ...). Definitely worth diving into if you want maintainable code.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Once again thanks for sharing valuable piece of information regarding `GlobalKey`. I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Thanks to [Günter Zöchbauer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/217408/g%C3%BCnter-z%C3%B6chbauer) for pointing me in right direction. I am using `GlobalKey` to get the things done. However use `GlobalKey` with [care](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51494550/6274128)

```
GlobalKey<_HomePageState> globalKey = GlobalKey();

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.help),
            onPressed: () {
             globalKey.currentState.methodA();
            },
          ),
        ),
        body: HomePage(key: globalKey),
      ),
    );
  }
}
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }

  void methodA() {}
}
```

Comment: Little bit confusion, Still using GlobalKey. Is it good way? pls clear

Comment: @iPatel It is good as long as you don't create lot of `GlobalKeys`

Comment: @Volleyball I have the same situation but i have the stateful widget in another class. so i need to _ from State class to call that function. Is it good practice?

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks that handling it like this violates OOP? (Law of demeter).

Answer (score 81):

I think the best practice in this case is using the way that the programmers of the Flutter used themselves!

Bellow code is an example from Flutter [source](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/retrieve-input). As you can see there in **MyCustomForm** widget if you want to access the text property of **TextField** widget *(which is the child of MyCustomForm widget in this example)* you need to use its controller like this...

```
class _MyCustomFormState extends State<MyCustomForm> {
  ...
  final myController = TextEditingController();
  ...
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      ...
      body: TextField(
        controller: myController,
      ),// TextField
      ...
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        ...
        onPressed: () {
          print(myController.text);
        },
        ...
      ),// FloatingActionButton
    );
  }
}
```

Now be inspired by this and also knowing the fact that Flutter pass its object parameters by reference so we need a controller class for our child class to be able to access child's fields and functions through the controller object *(like the TextField widget in previous example)*...in your case we can do it like this:

```
class HomePageController {
  void Function() methodA;
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  final HomePageController myController = HomePageController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.help),
            onPressed: () {
              myController.methodA();
            },
          ),// IconButton
        ),// AppBar
        body: HomePage(
          controller: myController,
        ),// HomePage
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  final HomePageController controller;

  HomePage({ this.controller });

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState(controller);
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  _HomePageState(HomePageController _controller) {
    _controller.methodA = methodA;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }

  void methodA() {}
}
```

As can be seen in this code **myController**'s reference passes through **HomePage** to reach the **_HomePageState**'s constructor and then gets the reference of **methodA** function... and now **methodA** is accessible in **MyApp** class via **myController**!

Hope it Helps! :))

Comment: Looks like most elegant solution to me

Comment: I'm trying to use this solution, but when the widget tree is rebuilt because of notifyListeners() the controller is null.

Comment: @jwasher thank u for your comment... you need to override the didUpdateWidget and reinitialize the variables just like how you did in the constructor... for example in this example:
override
  void didUpdateWidget(ProfileNumbersSection oldWidget) {
    _controller.methodA = methodA ;
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }

Comment: @ehsaneha clean and clever solution!

Comment: `Don't put any logic in createState.` https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/no_logic_in_create_state.html

Comment: The correct way to do this is to use ```@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.controller.methodA = methodA;
  }``` and remove _HomePageState initializing variables as pointed out by @Vlad

Comment: @ehsaneha I wish I could give you 10 thumbs ups

Comment: great answer but should be updated to link the controller in the `initState()` method to avoid putting logic in `createState` as @Vlad pointed out. Roddy R's code works for me!

Comment: I don't think the flutter team does it this way, providing `empty` Controllers and assigning the methods in initState

Comment: thank you for your answer, how can I pass a parameter to methodA ?

Answer (score 17):

## 2021

I believe this is the most robust solution using `typedef` and builder-like widget.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

typedef MyBuilder = void Function(BuildContext context, void Function() methodA);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  late void Function() myMethod;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.help),
            onPressed: () {
              // how can I call methodA from here?
              myMethod.call();
            },
          ),
        ),
        body: HomePage(builder: (BuildContext context, void Function() methodA) {
          myMethod = methodA;
        },),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final MyBuilder builder;

  const HomePage({Key? key, required this.builder}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    widget.builder.call(context, methodA);
    return Text('HomePage');
  }

  void methodA() {
    print('test');
  }
}
```

Comment: That is indeed an awesome solution, I'm going to have a look on it.

Comment: Thanks, this is really great! Does anyone know if there are any negative consequences of putting `widget.builder.call(context, methodA);` inside the build method? Actually I have noticed it doesn't execute the `methodA` when the build method runs so it should be fine.

Answer (score 11):

The above answer did not work for me, instead i just replaced the global key and it worked very well:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      leading: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.help),
        onPressed: () {
         //call it like this:
         HomePage.globalKey.currentState.methodA();
        },
      ),
    ),
    body: HomePage(),
  ),
);
 }
}


class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
//Add this key like this:
static final GlobalKey<_HomePageState> globalKey = GlobalKey();
super(key: globalKey);

@override
 _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container();
 }

 void methodA() {}
}
```

Hope everything is working:)

Comment: Thank you, this really gave answer to my long time search.

Comment: Expected a class member. Try placing this code inside a class member.

Comment: I apreciate this great answer! :)

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you can't do that because `_HomePageState` is private. Delete the `_` symbol ahead of HomePageState, so it will be public and you can call methodA() using the `HomePageState().methodA();`

Comment: First, I can do `_HomePageState().methodA()` without having me to delete `_`, second, instantiating `HomePageState` is not a good way to call `methodA()`, cause I will be creating a new state.

Comment: Personally I'd prefer Alex's solution. I don't see why it should be downvoted.
You can create the HomePage instance in the build method, before returning the MaterialApp. Then you can pass it in the body:, and reference it in the onPressed callback.

Comment: @FJJ As far as I know, you should not create 2 instance of the state. And for the tiny work like this, never!!!

Comment: I agree with Alex Adrianov it becomes private when you use '_'

Comment: @John It's "file private" when you use '_'. It means you can access it from another class in same file. But not from other file.

Answer (score 0):

I use the inherited concept of the object.
I am using the `TextEditingController`.

1. Assign this `TextEditingController` to the parent page.
2. Pass this controller into the child widget.
3. Put the child function into the `addListener` at the `initState`.
4. Using this controller in the parent function like `controller.text = '${controller.text}_'`.

So, when this parent function works, the controller value will change and the child function will work.

Answer (score -1):

Calling parent function can be done by a `callback`, but calling child function from a parent wouldn't be necessary I think. If your parent widget is `StateFull` you just need to `setState(() {});` to refresh the child widget, why you call child function.