# How to execute function when a variable is not null Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, future, statefulwidget

I have this code in _MyAppState in my main.dart :

```
     var _p3provider;
     @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        P3provider p3provider = new P3provider();
        authentification(p3provider);
        _p3provider = p3provider;
      }
```

I pass the variable _p3provider as p3provider to MyHomePage statefulWidget of my main.dart,

Here is some code of _MyHomePageState :

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (widget.p3provider.jsession_id == null) {
      Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), (){
        getTasks();
      }); 
    } else {
      getTasks();
    }
  }
```

To execute my getTasks function I need the jsession_id variable from p3provider object to be initialized. This variable is initialized in the initState of _MyAppState at this line : *authentification(p3provider);* .

The problem is that both the initState of _MyAppState and _MyHomePageState are executed at the same time so if I directly call *getTasks()* in the initState of _MyHomePageState it will return an error because *p3provider.jsession_id* will not have been initialized yet.

To avoid this error I used a Future.delayed after a checking if the variable is null, but I don't think this solution is optimal, I would like the function getTasks() to be executed directly when jsession_id become not null.

If anyone has an idea on how to do this, you are more than welcome ! :)

Comment: have you tried using Future.the() function?

Comment: Just tried it, thanks, Future.then((widget.p3provider.jsession_id){
      getTasks();
    }); but put me an error doesn't recognize widget.p3provider.jsession_id and says "instance member then can't be accessed using static access"

Comment: happy to help you

Comment: you were to fast bro, it didn't work actually I posted my comment by error while redacting it

Comment: please update your question and code

Comment: check my code, I edited it !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239278/discussion-between-diwyansh-and-js1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution :

I define this class :

```
class HomePageController{
  var getTasks;
}
```

Which I instanciate in _MyAppState :

```
final HomePageController myController = HomePageController();
```

I pass it down to MyHomePage widget :

```
home: MyHomePage(controller: myController),
```

And in the initState of _MyHomePageState I assign my function getTasks() to the controller variable getTasks :

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.controller.getTasks = getTasks;
  }
```

Now I can execute getTasks via the controller in _MyAppState :

```
@override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    authentification().then((value){
      myController.getTasks();
  }
```

Here is the topic where I got it : [Flutter calling child class function from parent class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53692798/flutter-calling-child-class-function-from-parent-class)