# How to open screen from side when clicked on top left button click(hamburger icon)?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I wish to open a side menu from left when clicked on an icon.

[image: top header]

Code:

```
class _MovieScreenState extends State<MovieScreen> {


MovieBloc _bloc;
 final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _bloc = MovieBloc();

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      drawer: new Drawer(),
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xffFAFCF7), // status bar color
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        elevation: 0.0,
        leading: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 17),
          child: RawMaterialButton(
            onPressed: _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer(),
            child: new Icon(
              Icons.menu,
              // color: Colors.black,
              size: 25.0,
            ),
            shape: new CircleBorder(),
            elevation: 4.0,
            fillColor: Colors.white,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
          ),
          ...
```

So, onTap i wish to open the screen from the left with full screen cover. Also, will it be possible to open the side screen if swipe towards to right from left is done on home screen.
Thanks

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47435655/5734205) might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible and the Widget you are looking for is `Drawer`

Pass param `drawer` into your Scaffold and you will see hamburger icon

```
class LeftMenu extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Container(child: 
      ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children:  // your widgets that you want to put inside
      )
   )
 }
}
Scaffold(
  drawer: Drawer(
    child: LeftMenu()
  )
);
```

And now it's possible to open it with hamburger menu or with swipe from right to the left.

You can read more about it in official tutorial: [Drawer](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/drawer)

Comment: how to call this drawer from `InkWell onTap`

Comment: You have add some key to your Scaffold: `final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();`

`Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey, ......`

and then you can open it in your onTap: `_scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer()`

Comment: there is this error
`The expression here has a type of 'void', and therefore can't be used.
Try checking to see if you are using the correct API; there might be a function or call that returns void you didn't expect. Also check type parameters and variables which might also be void.dart(use_of_void_result)`

Comment: change it to: `onPressed: (){_scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();}`