# flutter opening a drawer using a button inside a scaffold body

Tags: flutter, mobile, navigation-drawer

**What I have**
A custom button with onpress to open a drawer, my build snippet : (**inside MyClassState**)

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
      key: _key,
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Row(children: [

ElevatedButton(
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
    child: Icon(
      Icons.settings,
      size: 38,
      color: Colors.white,
    ),
  ),
  onPressed: () => _key.currentState?.openEndDrawer(),
), 

]),]),))
```

method globalkey _key is used (after reading some solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47435231/open-drawer-on-clicking-appbar))

```
Class MyClassState extends State<MyClass> {
    GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _key = GlobalKey();
  ...
}
```

**What I expected**

The drawer opens on press/tap

**The current behaviour result**

Nothing happens on tap, but I can open the drawer using slide gesture.

What did I do wrong in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't declared `endDrawer` in scaffold, Here is the your updated code

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
      key: _key,
      endDrawer: Drawer(      /// this is missing in your code
        child: Container(
          width: 200,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Row(children: [

ElevatedButton(
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
    child: Icon(
      Icons.settings,
      size: 38,
      color: Colors.white,
    ),
  ),
  onPressed: () => _key.currentState?.openEndDrawer(),
), 

]),]),))
```

Comment: OHHH i did declare it, but i declare as "drawer: Drawer( ..."

do take note that i can open the drawer using slide left to right gesture. so that's why it leaves me wondering why it does not on tap of a button.

is there a difference between endDrawer and drawer?

Comment: @vontdeux One is open from left side and second one is open from right side. That's a difference between `Drawer` and `EndDrawer`